# Can I catch the creatures in the infinite room? If so, how?

Tags: botanicula

How can I catch these critters in level four (the caves)? They run away and end up on a completely different area no matter whether I follow them or attempt to cut them off.

[image: infinite room]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** But if you chase them enough, you'll get their card.<sup>[1](http://www.gamezebo.com/games/botanicula/walkthrough)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You're not meant to do anything with them. Possibly they contribute towards the collector cards.